# Shortcut to Jump to definition in current file/tab in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Brand new pycharm user, but couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I come form subline text 3 which had a super convienient short cut ^R which you would then type a few characters and options for the class/method/function definitions in the currently opened file.

It's s complicated project with lots of files, so doing `SHIFT` `SHIFT` (search everywhere) and typing brings up a ton of stuff, so I basically have to type the entire definition name exactly right before it shows up much less gets to the top of the list.

Is there a way of doing similar to `SHIFT` `SHIFT`, but limited to just the current file?  Either out of the box of some customization to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

While maybe not *exactly* what you're looking for, maybe PyCharm's [view structure of source file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html) feature may be useful. Use `Alt+7` to get a window, or `Ctrl+F12` to get a pop-up. In the pop-up, you can begin typing to narrow results. Selecting an item and hitting `Enter` will teleport you to the definition.

**Original Answer Below:**

Pressing `Ctrl+Shift+I` will give you a preview of the definition in a pop up. If you hit `Enter` while the pop up is open, you'll be teleported to the source of the definition.

If you just want the docstring, you can hit `Ctrl+Q` for "quick documentation."

Sources:

[Code reference information](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-reference-information.html)

[Editor basics](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2019.1/using-code-editor.html)

Comment: What I'm looking for is allow me to search for a definition in the current file, It looks like Ctrl+Shift+I/Ctrl+Q requires I have a call to the definition to start from and is not limited to the current file. I use Ctrl+B to jump to a definition if I have a call to start from.

Comment: @nephlm - Looks like I slightly misunderstood your question, sorry about that! When you start typing, do you not get a little pop-up list of possible suggestions? I use that feature pretty heavily - I can simply use the arrow keys and `enter` to pick a suggestion definition from PyCharm.

Comment: Ctrl+F12 was exactly what I was looking for.  You just made my life a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

in pycharm 2022.1.3 it was ctrl+shift+I and then f4.